# How to get instance of object code was executed from

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting the caller of a method in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393758/getting-the-caller-of-a-method-in-c-sharp)

Is it possible to get the instance of the object that a method is executed from?

For example...

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void PrintMyName()
    {
        NamePrinter np = new NamePrinter();
        np.PrintName();
    }
}

public class NamePrinter
{
    public void PrintName()
    {
        Person p = ?;
        Console.Writeline(p.Name);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Person person = new Person() { Name = "Brandon"; }
        person.PrintMyName();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to find 'p' in the PrintName method?

EDIT:  The problem in the above piece of code could be solved lots of different ways and very easily.  Please assume I'm not stupid and that this is just the easiest piece of code I could come up with to make my question clear.

Comment: Add an instance of `Person` to the `NamePrinter` class. Or pass it to the `NamePrinter.PrintName` method.

Comment: why not to pass `Person` as parameter?

Comment: @leppie I'm not a idiot.  Clearly this is a contrived piece of code.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: Huh? What are you talking about? It is not (really) possible and I gave you 2 suggestions.

Comment: The alternative is to use dynamic binding, but it is a lot more effort than suggested answers. See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153896/Dynamic-Binding-in-C

Comment: @DanielHilgarth If you'd just stick to the actual question I asked rather than getting caught up in the details then it wouldn't seem so complicated ;)  Matthew Watson's answer was all I was looking for.

Comment: @leppie +1 for the interesting link.  Obviously you're right that it's not a desirable solution, but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Fyi: for more context you can see my comment on his answer.  If you have any thing to respond to that that can't fit in a comment then I'll be happy to post another question for you to answer.  But basically, I was pretty sure what I wanted wasn't possible from the beginning but I wanted to verify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this because:

- There's no way to know which object type it might have been called from. Just because you call it from an instance of a class called Person doesn't mean that's the only way it could be called.
- It might not be called from an object instance at all. It could have been called from a static method.

When a method in a class is called, nothing about the calling code is pushed onto the stack (other than the method's arguments) so there is simply no information you can get hold of to use in this way.

The correct solution in your case is, I think, to add a parameter of type Person to PrintName() (which I imagine you've already considered?)

Comment: Yes, I was just looking at the way TransactionScope works and wondering if the same sort of functionality could be applied using the calling object instance as the context rather than the current thread.